# Does ArcGIS.com support dynamic map services (or only feature services and tiled services)?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

Using ArcGIS Server it is possible to publish a map service, which has a URL like http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/USA_1990-2000_Population_Change/MapServer/1

In this case, the "1" refers to the particular polygon layer. It's possible to create a [featureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer.html) from this REST endpoint.

When I publish a map to ArcGIS.com the options are "Feature Access" or "Tiled Mapping". This means that the REST endpoint has **/FeatureServer/** rather than **/MapServer/** in the URL.

Am I correct in the assumption that ArcGIS.com doesn't support [dynamic map services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_map_service/0154000002m7000000/), and only supports feature services and tiled services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the above assumption is correct, and ArcGIS.com does not support map services.

There are some tips at http://communityhub.esriuk.com/journal/2013/5/29/improving-the-performance-of-complex-features-in-arcgis-onli.html on improving the performance of complex features, by pre-generalizing them. (I found that these tips worked well)

Comment: I always thought that the feature and tiled map services currently available to publish to ArcGIS.com were just types of map services (feature & tiled).  Meaning map services is just a more generalized/encompassing name.

Answer (score 1):

I think the terminology should be clarified. We are dealing with three types of services:
1. Tiled Map Services,
2. Dynamic Map Services and
3. Feature Services

From my experience, #1 and #3 are supported by ArcGIS online, while #2 is not.